# How to always validate JWT without guards decorator? (Nest.js + passport)

Tags: node.js, jwt, graphql, passport.js, nestjs

I using nest.js + passport + jwt + graphql in project.

If there is a token, then decoded information,
want to get undefined if don't have token.

Always must have Guards to receive decoded tokens.

Can I selectively generate 401 error?

```js
@Module({
  providers: [
    JwtStrategy,
  ],
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'hi',
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '1d' },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {
}


export class GqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  getRequest(context: ExcutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context)
    return ctx.getContext().req
  }
}


export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: config.jwt.secret,
    })
  }
  
  validate(payload: JwtPayload): any {
    return { user_id: +payload.user_id , username: payload.username }
  }
}

@Resolver(() => Test)
export class TestResolver {
  @UseGuards(GqlAuthGuard) // I want to get validated users without guards.
  @Query(() => Test)
  startTest(
    @User() user: any, // req.user
  ) {
    console.log(user)
  }
}
```

---

I don't know if it's possible, but I want this code.

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
 if (req.headers.token) { // optional
  try {
   req.user = verify(req.headers.token)
  } catch (err) {
   req.user = undefined
  }
 }

 next()
})

app.get((req, res, next) => {
 if (req.user) {
  ...
 }
})
```

Comment: What would be the purpose of getting undefined if there is no token to decode? Wouldn't that mean that it is an unauthenticated user and you should return a 401?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel
If have a token in headers, I want to search with the information of that user.
But, must have a Guard to proceed with the validation and, if there is no token, output 401.
It is difficult to use the Guard because it must have a token.

Comment: I mean, in the guard you can say `if (!token) return false` and nest can handle the rest of it

Comment: Added content to the text.
This document says that the req must be returned from the Guard.
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication#graphql

I don't know if I'm mistaken...

Comment: In the express code snippet you added, what do you want to do if there is no token? Right now it looks like you just go to `next()` and don't really care if a token is given or not

Comment: If there is no token or an invalid token comes in, it calls next () immediately.
And if the token exists and is valid, want to run verify.

Should I separate the resolver altogether?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you would send the user on in an authenticated route if the token is missing or invalid. Wouldn't that mean the user is unauthenticated?

Comment: I want to add a condition to the business logic depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: So, where do you want to return the 401 from? Because in your question you wanted to selectively return a 401, but in the express snippet there's nothing about returning an error.

Comment: It is not necessary to return 401.
If the token is invalid or there is no token, req.user can be treated as undefined.

Is it possible in nest.js + graphql?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply global guards like so

```
async function bootstrap(): Promise<void> {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

    const reflector = app.get(Reflector);
    app.useGlobalGuards(new GqlAuthGuard(reflector));

    await app.listen(process.env.PORT);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer!
I need both Query that does not require authentication and Query that is required.
Verify token in one Query, but do not want to generate 401 errors.

Comment: you can bypass global guard by setting metadata to your query by implementing @Public decorator
there are couple of examples in my blog https://trejgun.github.io/